# Page listing Custom Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

I have Custom Posts (actually Pages) that I can view on my default page (page-home.php) but how do I create a separate page, with the exact same content, and link to it?

The page-home.php (the default WP page) code is currently this:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home News */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="inner-content" class="twelvecol first clearfix">
                        <div id="main" class="main-home rsFull-Site" role="main">
                            <?php // NEWS ?>
                                <?php $args = array( 'post_type'=> 'wigwam','post_parent' => 0,'posts_per_page' => 6); query_posts( $args ); if (have_posts()) : ?>
                                <article id="the-wigwam" class="window rsContent">
                                    <div class="gallery wrap">
                                    <p><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/wigwam-logo.png" alt="The Wigwam"></p>
                                    <div id="masonry">
                                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                            <div class="wigwam wigwam-tile">

                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                        <div class="wigwam-thumb ImageWrapper">
                                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('wigwam-images'); ?>
                                                            <div class="ImageOverlayAl"></div>
                                                            <div class="Buttons CStyleHe">
                                                                <div class="wigwam-hover">
                                                                    <h3><?php the_category(', '); ?></h3>
                                                                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                                                    <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
                                                                    <div class="sub-header">
                                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php global $post; $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_sub_heading', true ); echo $text; ?></a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <p class="more-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">More &gt;</a></p>  
                                                                </div>                                                              
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="wigwam-thumb-heading">
                                                                <h3><?php the_category(', '); ?></h3>
                                                                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>

                                            </div>                                          
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pattern"></div>
                                </article>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php // END OF NEWS ?> 
                    </div> <?php // end #main ?>
                </div> <?php // end #inner-content ?>
            </div> <?php // end #content ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It works great, but how should I save it so that it's a separate page? And how do I then reference that page?

I'd create a new Page in the WP Admin, but I don't believe I have access to PHP there, do I? I'm sure this must be very simple to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to access any php for that, simply create a new page and select the "Home News" page template for that page from the "Page Attributes" meta box.

[image]